# Converting units of measurment in R which contain different measurement units from string to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I have a dataframe where one character-variable looks like the following:

```
Var1
10 km
100 m
2.7 km
3 km
500 m
```

What would be the best approach to transform this variable into a numeric one but also convert all values that are kilometers into meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Var1 <- c("10 km", "100 m", "2.7 km", "3 km", "500 m")
strsplit(Var1, " ")
sapply(strsplit(Var1, " "), function(x) ifelse(x[2] == "km", as.numeric(x[[1]])*1000, as.numeric(x[[1]])))

[1] 10000   100  2700  3000   500
```

This solution only accepts "m" and "km" as unit. If you need further units, you can just define your own function to do the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
ifelse(grepl('k', Var1) == TRUE,  as.numeric(sub(" .*", "", Var1)) * 10^3, as.numeric(sub(" .*", "", Var1)))
```